# Output array in order

Tags: php

I have some code that our developer who is no longer here wrote for us. It is armoring specs for something. The array is listed in the order it has to be shown at all times. However its not showing up on the front end in  this order. Can some one tell me whats wrong with the code and point me in the right direction

```
$explode_armoring_level = explode(',',$nij);

        # list all armoring levels  
        $armoring_level_array = array('ii','iiia','iii','iv');

        # remove any empty values and reset array to parse
        $remove_empty_array = array_filter($explode_armoring_level);

        # count array so we do not show active class when array empty
        $armoring_level_count = count($remove_empty_array);

        # loop through all selected levels for posted ID/vehicle id
        foreach($remove_empty_array as $key => $eal)
        {
            # find last value in array and set class
            if ($eal == end($explode_armoring_level) && $armoring_level_count > 0)
            {
                # returns active armoring level list
                $vehicle_data .= '<li class="active">'.ucwords($eal).'</li>' . "\r\n";
            }
            else
            {
                # returns active armoring level list
                $vehicle_data .= '<li>'.ucwords($eal).'</li>' . "\r\n";
            }
        }


        # run loop to find remaining armoring levels that were not selected
        foreach($explode_armoring_level as $ala)
        {
            if (in_array($ala, $armoring_level_array)) 
            {
                unset($armoring_level_array[array_search($ala,$armoring_level_array)]);
            }           
        }

        $count = 1;

        # output remaining armoring levels
        foreach($armoring_level_array as $key => $alag)
        {
            if($count == 1 && $armoring_level_count == 0)
            {
                # returns active armoring level list
                $vehicle_data .= '<li class="active non-active">'.ucwords($alag).'</li>' . "\r\n";
            }
            else
            {
                # returns active armoring level list
                $vehicle_data .= '<li class="active">'.ucwords($alag).'</li>' . "\r\n"; 
            }

            $count++;
        }
```

## select vehicle based on posting id

```
    $get_vehicle_details = "SELECT post_id,meta_key,meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = '".$post->ID."'";
    $get_vehicle_details_result = $link->query($get_vehicle_details);

    # error array
    $err = array();

    # loop through results
    while($row = $get_vehicle_details_result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        # identify meta_key you want and assign value
        if($row['meta_key'] == 'euro-norm')     {$euro_norm      = $row['meta_value'];}
        if($row['meta_key'] == 'nsa')           {$nsa            = $row['meta_value'];}
        if($row['meta_key'] == 'nij')           {$nij            = $row['meta_value'];}
        if($row['meta_key'] == 'ul-armor-level'){$ul_armor_level = $row['meta_value'];}
        if($row['meta_key'] == 'vpam')          {$vpam           = $row['meta_value'];}
    }

    # if values are Empty/FALSE then push into error array
    if($euro_norm == '')     {array_push($err, 'euro_norm');}
    if($nsa == '')           {array_push($err, 'nsa');}
    if($nij == '')           {array_push($err, 'nij');}
    if($ul_armor_level == ''){array_push($err, 'ul_armor_level');}
    if($vpam == '')          {array_push($err, 'vpam');}        

    # count total errors
    $row_error = count($err);

    # if error count is less than 5 or not 5 / show vechile data
    if($row_error < 5 or $row_error != 5)
    {
```

Comment: what is the initial value of `$nij`?

Comment: I updated the code with the additional information needed possibly